# Wierd issue with using task schedule to process php script

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have created a task schedule which processes a batch file which in turn processes a php script ("sendtext.php") to send text message. The "sendtext.php" includes another php file ("prefs.php") which checks whether a particular text file exists or not. If it does, the process continues, otherwise it gives an alert and redirects to different page to create the text file first. 
Now, if I run the batch file manually, it does send the text message. When I run the scheduled task which runs the same batch file, it gives an alert from included file ("prefs.php") because it can't find the text file. All php files and batch file are in the same folder.
I think it's some kind of path issue with task schedule.
Please help!!!

Comment: You should post the contents of the batch file I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your .bat file, use the change directory command (`cd`) to your program root directory.
After you have configured environment variables for php, you can run php on the next line and you will not have any issues with include, require, etc. statements. If you don't configure environment variables, the second line should point to your php.exe directory: c:\program files\php...php.exe

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myprogram-dev\
php execute-this.php
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the script normally, you are running it from the folder it's in. Cron jobs assume they are running from a different location (or different folder even, for example if you run cron tasks under the root user it's assuming you are executing the script from the directory /root).

A better way to include your file(s) would be something like this:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/prefs.php');
```

The constant will then ensure that the path is relative to the current script that's including said file. I.e. if my script is /var/www/vhosts/website.com/scripts/test.php, then it will look in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/scripts/ for prefs.php when including.

Comment: All my php and batch files are in "C:/wamp/www/reminders/" folder. Can you please elaborate your answer? What should I use as _DIR_ .thanks.

Comment: That is a constant that automatically will assume the local directory.  You don't replace it with anything. You simply use the code :p Not sure how to elaborate further. Perhaps you should do an echo of the constant so you can see it in action first hand. The cron tasks do not assume they are executing the script from the same directory you are is all.

Comment: Thanks I got it but it seems I'll have to do that everywhere I have made reference to any file in my scripts. I actually figured out what the problem is. I needed to define "Start In" option in the schedule task to the directory where my files are located. I am still struggling to find a working solution on how to set that option when I create the schedule task from a batch file via "SCHTASKS" command. It doesn't offer that option. I read some other ideas but no success yet.